# How to integrate Crittercism into an Xcode workspace with multiple sub-projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, crittercism

I´m working in a workspace in Xcode which has 6 sub-projects in it. The SDK works perfectly in the main project (the one running the AppDelegate) and I´m receiving all the detailed crashes reports that happen in it. But if there is a crash that occurs in any of the other projects, I also receive the crash report but it doesn´t contain the complete stacktrace showing the exact line inside this project (I believe it´s because the projects have different bundle identifier).

I tried adding the framework on each project settings file with no results. Also calling *[Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"APP_ID"]* with different App Id´s for each project gives me duplication errors.

Is there something I´m missing or this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a way to integrate Apteligent SDK into xCode with multiple projects. You can find the detailed information right under this link :

http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/Integrate-with-multiple-xcode-projects

Please be noted that this would not be possible to mention multiple App IDs for one project.